# что такое барьер? (структуры данных)

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных, терминология

По предмету "Алгоритмы и структуры данных" дали задание создать:

> Структуру данных для организации линейного односвязного списка
>
> Структура данных: очередь (FIFO)  с барьером.
>
> Представление памяти - динам. память.

Все, в принципе понятно, кроме **барьера**.

Кто то может простым языком объяснить, что это, и с чем его едят?

Comment: В первый раз слышу такое название — может, вам лучше спросить у лектора, что он имел в виду?

Comment: @VladD Не, я уже однажды такое слышал, сейчас попробую описать в ответе.

Comment: Наверно, имеется в виду sentinel узел, который показывает конец списка. И почему "список, представляющий очередь" а не "очередь, реализованная в виде списка"? Первая формулировка шизофреническая.

Comment: Да, действительно немного шизофренично, сейчас поправлю, спасибо.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

У вас имеется линейный неупорядоченный список элементов, а именно, в данном случае - `FIFO` (не будем заморачиваться с тем, что такая структура хранения данных - это *очередь*, будем называть списком).

Однажды вам понадобится выполнить поиск в этом списке элемента по значению, но так как элементы в нем не упорядочены, то и вариант поиска всего один: полный обход списка поэлементно (если без непосредственного применения сортировки перед поиском, конечно же).

На каждом шаге поиска вам придется проверять не выходите ли вы за границы вашего списка, а лишь затем сравнивать текущий элемент списка с искомым. Существует несколько способов проверки этого факта: один из них - установить в конец списка уникальный элемент, натыкаясь на который вы будете уверены, что достигли конца списка. При этом необходимо обеспечить уникальность данного элемента. Вот именно этот элемент и будет называться `барьером` (т.е. дальше него искать не стоит - вы обошли весь список).

В вашем же случае с `FIFO (First In, First Out)` придется добавлять *барьерный элемент* в список самым последним в связи с порядком обхода данного списка, а затем при обходе списка проверять не является ли текущий элемент *барьером*, т.е. вы должны заранее знать значение барьера.

Comment: Спасибо, разъяснили. Только вот зачем он в очереди не очень понятно, ведь очередь на то и очередь, что мы имеем доступ только к первому элементу... Хотя, наверно, все учебные задания немного не практичны и бессмысленны..

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI Ну, _барьер_ - это несколько абстрактная вещь. Например, в плюсах, если элементы вашего списка представляют собой указатели на узлы (`node`'ы), то вместо какого-то "особого" узлового элемента в качестве барьера можно воспользоваться просто `nullptr`'ом (т.е. стандартные средства языка позволяют это легко сделать и программист может даже не задумываться о том, что он применил такой подход).

Comment: @ANUCHEEKIBREEKI На счет вашего вопроса из комментария выше непосредственно: да, вы имеете доступ лишь к первому элементу, который имеет ссылку на второй элемент и так далее, но как при обходе списка вы узнаете, что вы обошли его весь? Либо вы  выставляете в конец списка _барьер_, либо, например, имеете поле внутри вашего списка, в котором хранится количество элементов списка и при каждом добавлении/удалении элемента в список вы это поле увеличиваете/уменьшаете и перед обращением к следующему элементу списка сравниваете номер этого элемента в списке с количеством элементов в нем вообще.

Comment: @VladD Да я одновременно с вами поясняющий комментарий написал, вы даже раньше были :)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive: В любом случае, большая часть пояснения есть в ответе.

Comment: Требуется ли делать списки с этими sentinel'ями в реальной работе программиста? Структура данных должна быть универсальной, а использование уникального элемента в качестве барьера снижает универсальность. Похоже, все это просто далекая от реальности теория.

Comment: честно говоря, единственный раз сталкивался с барьером - когда в универе проходили линейный поиск. тогда барьер просто был элементом в конце списка, которому присваивалось искомое значение. Таким образом можно было сэкономить на проверке на конец списка. Очередь с барьером - это какое-то странное.

Comment: @zRrr, да, с очередью sentinel выглядит искусственно, а вот  в описанной [здесь](http://cs.mipt.ru/docs/comp/rus/programming/algorithms/niman_sort_poisk/main.pdf) реализации rb-tree все листья дерева являются  “сторожевыми ” (sentinel), что сильно упрощает код.